# Failed to Start Login Service keeps appearing on boot

Tags: kali-linux

When I boot my Raspberry-Pi with kali linux installed, the screen prints what its doing and so on whilst booting. However, I keep seeing the error message

```
[FAILED] Failed To Start Login Service
```

**Edit:** Here is the login service error:

```
systemd-logind.service - Login Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2019-02-14 10:13:32 GMT; 46s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-logind.service(8)
           man:logind.conf(5)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
  Process: 842 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 842 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
```

Everything works but booting takes a lot longer and have to keep waiting for the login service to work.

Anyone know how to fix/prevent this?

Comment: There should be more information in the journal: `journalctl -u systemd-logind`. Or perhaps an [internet search](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=systemd-logind+abrt)?